# SQL, duplicate count rows preceding unbounded

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is some dummy data:

```
DECLARE @trial TABLE  (id int identity, val int)

INSERT INTO @trial (val)
VALUES (1), (3),(8), (10), (8),(3), (1), (10),(8), (1), (3),(10)

select * from @trial order by id
```

Here is my expected output:

```
val  duplicateindex
  1  0
  3  0
  8  0
  10 0
  8  1
  3  1
  1  1
 10  1
  8  2
  1  2
  3  2
 10  2
```

I'm basically trying to find the number of duplicates of the current row value in the rows preceding unbounded. It's okay to count the current row also in the duplicate so even if all the duplicateindex values are shifted by 1, that's also fine.

Any ideas please? I'm using SQL Server 2016. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `COUNT()` window function:

```
select id, val, count(*) over (partition by val order by id) duplicateindex
from @trial
order by id
```

You may subtract 1 from `duplicateindex`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bca783992a846b6775e67d6bf6bd09dd).
Results:

```
> id | val | duplicateindex
> -: | --: | -------------:
>  1 |   1 |              1
>  2 |   3 |              1
>  3 |   8 |              1
>  4 |  10 |              1
>  5 |   8 |              2
>  6 |   3 |              2
>  7 |   1 |              2
>  8 |  10 |              2
>  9 |   8 |              3
> 10 |   1 |              3
> 11 |   3 |              3
> 12 |  10 |              3
```

Comment: select * from (
select id, val, count(*) over (partition by val order by id) duplicateindex
from @trial
)tbl
order by id

Comment: thanks a lot. can i presume the code i have written above will ensure order is preserved as expected?

Comment: You don't need the subquery.

Comment: i need to make use of the duplicateindex in some further processing so hence the subquery

Comment: Then your query will return all the rows ordered by id.

Comment: yes that's fine. but can i presume duplicateindex is reliable as it is partitioned by val & ordered by id in the subquery?

Comment: It is partitioned by val because you want duplicates of val. It is ordered by id because this is the only reliable order in th etable.